# Работа с датой в golang

Tags: mysql, golang, mariadb

Я из бд загружаю данные, одно из полей в формате date (YYYY.MM.DD).
Я его сохраняю в переменную и потом отдаю клиенту. Как вывести формат даты в виде DD.MM.YYYY либо средствами golang либо,что б база отдавала уже в таком виде?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если через базу

```
select DATE_FORMAT(r.BeginDate, '%d.%m.%Y ') as BeginDate from table
```

Если через golang

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func main() {
  ttime := time.Now()
  tt := ttime.Format("02.01.2006")
  fmt.Printf(tt)
}
```